# Lua table sort with string key

Tags: sorting, lua, lua-table

I need help on this table

```
tbl = {
    Noa={10,0,3},
    melvin={5,3,1},
    jeex={500,0,2},
    kiim={100,2,3}
}
```

I neet all valueson this table, sort by first value on table
example.

output>

```
jeex   500 ,0,2
kiim   100 ,2,3
Noa    10,0,3
melvin 5,3,1
```

Comment: Tables cannot be sorted. You can sort the keys, though.

Answer (score 1):

Only table elements with numerical indices have an order. You can't sort a table where the keys are strings. So your first step is to create a table that actually has an order. You do this by iterating through the elements of your current table and insert a value in a new table based on the current one, one that contains both the key and the value.

```
local array = {}
for key, value in pairs(tbl) do
  array[#array + 1] = {key = key, value = value}
end
```

Once you have an actual array, *then* you can sort it with `table.sort`.

Comment: i have a simple solution||

function TableSortByValue(tbl)
 --sort by first value on table
 array={}
 for _,i in pairs(tbl) do
  table.insert(i,_)
  --tbl={[1...]={1,1,1,name}}
  array[table.getn(array)+1]=i
 end
 table.sort(array, function(a,b)
  return a[1] > b[1]
 end)
 return array
end